# Object creation by variable name as property name and variable value as value

Tags: javascript

Consider below code

```
var myVariable = true;
var myObject = {myVariable};  // !! syntax of object creation !!
console.log(myObject);
console.log(myObject.myVariable);
```

Here is output

```
{ myVariable: true }
true
```

I have never saw the above syntax of Object creation. But it is working somehow. I didn't found any documentation station object creation in that way.

**When I uglify this code. It will not work as desired**

Is it good to create object like this?
Does all browser support this syntax?
Is there any documentation stating stating object creation in this way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: That's a shortcut introduced with ES2015 -> [Object initializer - New notations in ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: its a right one. without add key value pair in the object .it add the key name from the variable name

Comment: Whatever uglifier you were using did not support ES6.

Comment: `{a}` is equal to `{'a': a}`. `a` is your variable.